# react-transition-group on Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-transition-group

I am conditionally rendering a Modal, with data being rendered into it on the previous click and as soon as the modal is closed, that data is removed from the state. (All the data related to modal is being stored in the parent component).

Now I am using CSSTransition from react-transition-group, to animate the mounting/unmounting of the Modal, code snippet which is calling Modal is like

```
<CSSTransition  
 in={modal.status && modal.state === 'MEDIA_INFO_MODAL'}  
 appear={true}  
 timeout={200}  
 nodeRef={modalRef}  
 classNames="my-node"  
 unmountOnExit  
\>
    <Modal ref={modalRef} modalClicker={modalHandler}>{modal.data}</Modal>
</CSSTransition>
```

And as it can be seen in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-react-transition-group-reactdom-createportal-forked-umphmk?file=/src/Modal.js) the Modal component after closing, is still rendered and in my case it is giving error because the `modal.data` becomes `null` as soon as I hit the close button from the modal, sending `null` in the Modal, causing error.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your sandbox (except a deprecation warning for ` findDOMNode`, which is probably coming from that `CSSTransition` component and not your code).

Comment: Actually the code in the codesandbox is not my project code, that is a sample code which shows that Modal component also re-renders when you close it, you can confirm this by console logging from the modal, you will see that after closing modal, the component renders again 2-3 times.

My problem is that how can we prevent that rendering, when we close the Modal.

My project is at [Github Link](https://github.com/daxter-army/home-server), in the screenshots you can see a modal, the problem is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure about the rest of your code, but it looks like you have too many things going on.  You can see in your sandbox example a clean way to animate a modal in and out.

```
<CSSTransition  
 in={modal.status && modal.state === 'MEDIA_INFO_MODAL'} 
 timeout={200} 
 classNames="my-node"  
 unmountOnExit  
\>
    <Modal modalClicker={modalHandler}>{modal?.data}</Modal>
</CSSTransition>
```

I do not know of a reason to pass a ref from the transition to the element, so I took it out. This exact method is how I do all my modals with react-transition-group.

Also, when you are accessing properties on an object that changes state to and from null, it is best to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when referring to it.

E.g.

```
modal?.data
```

It is syntactic sugar for checking if an object exists before accessing its properties

If you absolutely need to keep the component rendered, then you will need to remove `unmountOnExit`, but according to your described issue:

> modal.data becomes null as soon as I hit the close button

then your issue should be resolved by optional chaining.  If you keep the component mounted you will probably need to hide it with css, or make sure there is only null content inside the `Modal` component.

Comment: Thanks bro.... about the ref, it was giving me an depreciation warning about findDOMNode, so I provided it a ref, and the warning vanished.
```modal?.data``` can serve it for now 